# How do I sort two Excel userform ListBoxes that could have item moving to and from eachother

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Basically I'm filling the ListBoxes with column header names I'm choosing some for deletion. In the ListBox, I have two columns so the first one keeps track of the order and the second shows the header name. I want to sort by the first column to preserve the order if items get moved back and forth.

The bubble sort methods I did get work give such a result as (1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

[Picture of userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAmR3.png)

So here is my code populating the list box.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

colCount = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'How many headers to work with

For i = 0 To colCount - 1

 lBox_headersKeep.AddItem i
 lBox_headersKeep.List(i, 1) = Cells(1, i + 1)  'Add headers to this array
Next i

End Sub
```

And here's my code moving items back and forth. I would want the sort to happen here.

```
Private Sub cmd_sellectionRight_Click() 'move item from Left ListBox to Right
  Dim i As Long
  Dim c As Integer
  For i = 0 To lBox_headersKeep.listCount - 1 'start the loop to move right
   c = lBox_headersRemove.listCount 'get count in lBox_headersRemove
    If lBox_headersKeep.Selected(i) Then
        lBox_headersRemove.AddItem lBox_headersKeep.List(i)
        lBox_headersRemove.List(c, 1) = lBox_headersKeep.List(i, 1)
      lBox_headersKeep.RemoveItem i
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_sellectionLeft_Click() 'move item from Right ListBox back to Left
  Dim i As Long
  Dim c As Integer
  For i = 0 To lBox_headersRemove.listCount - 1 'start the loop to move left
   c = lBox_headersKeep.listCount 'get count in lBox_headersKeep
    If lBox_headersRemove.Selected(i) Then
        lBox_headersKeep.AddItem lBox_headersRemove.List(i)
        lBox_headersKeep.List(c, 1) = lBox_headersRemove.List(i, 1)
      lBox_headersRemove.RemoveItem i
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

EDIT!!! I should have added this to begin with but this is the bubble sort I'm using.

```
Public Function BubbleSrt(ArrayIn, Ascending As Boolean)

Dim SrtTemp As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


If Ascending = True Then
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i) > ArrayIn(j) Then
                 SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
                 ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
                 ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
Else
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn) To UBound(ArrayIn)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn)
             If ArrayIn(i) < ArrayIn(j) Then
                 SrtTemp = ArrayIn(j)
                 ArrayIn(j) = ArrayIn(i)
                 ArrayIn(i) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
End If

BubbleSrt = ArrayIn

End Function
```

Comment: You need to modify the bubble sort so it treats the values as numbers, not text.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I included the bubble sort I'm using in the post. How would I modify it? I have tried but do not understand it very well.

Comment: `If CDbl(ArrayIn(i)) > CDbl(ArrayIn(j)) Then` etc for the other block

Comment: Hmm, I made the change and now I'm getting run time 9 (subscript out of range) on "CDbl(ArrayIn(i))"

Comment: That change alone should not cause that specific error.

Comment: Am I not passing the array correctly. This is what I'm doing. myArr = lBox_headersRemove.List myArr = BubbleSrt(myArr, True)

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/05/24/sorting-a-multicolumn-listbox/

Comment: Oh, so I was getting Run Time 9 because I wasn't specifying the column in the two-column array. This worked 'If CDbl(ArrayIn(i, 0)) > CDbl(ArrayIn(j, 0)) Then'

Comment: Yes sorry I skimmed your post a bit too much...

Answer (score 0):

This works for the 2D array from a listbox:

```
'Sort a 2D array ascending or descending
'  sortIndex should use the same base as the input array,
'    so sortIndex = 0 for the first column where array base is zero
Public Function BubbleSort2D(ArrayIn, sortIndex As Long, _
                           Optional AsNumbers As Boolean = True, _
                           Optional Ascending As Boolean = True)
    
    Dim i As Long, a, b, tmp
    Dim j As Long, c As Long
    
    For i = LBound(ArrayIn, 1) To UBound(ArrayIn, 1)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(ArrayIn, 1)
            
            If AsNumbers Then
                a = CDbl(ArrayIn(i, sortIndex))
                b = CDbl(ArrayIn(j, sortIndex))
            Else
                a = ArrayIn(i, sortIndex)
                b = ArrayIn(j, sortIndex)
            End If
             
            If IIf(Ascending, a > b, a < b) Then
                For c = LBound(ArrayIn, 2) To UBound(ArrayIn, 2)
                    tmp = ArrayIn(j, c)
                    ArrayIn(j, c) = ArrayIn(i, c)
                    ArrayIn(i, c) = tmp
                Next c
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
    BubbleSort2D = ArrayIn
End Function
```

Comment: Could I be getting runtime 9 because I'm using a two-column array?

Comment: Edited with a 2D-capable sort function

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for your help!